# Moshe taught Aharon the services of the Mishkan

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest, moshe-rabbeinu, korban, aharon

I heard that Moshe Rabeinu taught Aharon Hacohen and his sons how to perform the services of the Mishkan during the first seven days after it's inauguration. Is this correct? If so, where is it written?

Answer (score 2):

I recently heard this in a shiur and heard a deep lesson about it. If and when I recall it, I will bring it bli neder. For now though, [this Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.34.32.1) should suffice. On the pasuk:

> Afterward all the Israelites came near, and he instructed them
> concerning all that 'ה had imparted to him on Mount Sinai. (Shemot 34:32)

Rashi says:

> ואחרי כן נגשו AND AFTERWARDS [THE CHILDREN OF ISRAEL] STEPPED NIGH —
> After he (Moses) had taught the elders he used again to teach the
> section or the single Halacha in question to the Israelites. The
> Rabbis have taught: How was the system of teaching? Moses used to
> learn the law from the mouth of the Almighty; Aaron entered and Moses
> taught him his lesson. Now Aaron moved away and took his seat to the
> left of Moses. Then his (Aaron’s) sons entered and Moses taught them
> their lesson. They moved away and Eleazar took his seat to the right
> of Moses, whilst Ithamar sat down at Aaron’s left. The elders then
> entered and Moses taught them their lesson. The elders moved away and
> took their seat at the side. Finally the whole people entered and
> Moses taught them their lesson. Consequently what was taught came into
> the possession of the whole people once, into the possession of the
> elders twice, into the possession of Aaron’s sons thrice and into
> Aaron’s possession four times etc. — as it is stated in Eruvin 54b.

See also https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.6.2